# Cassandra 3.11.2 column metadata

Tags: cassandra, metadata, double-quotes

Where do C* store information about "double quotation marks" used in column name?

It's not in system_schema.column but in C* 3.11.2 it's obligatory to use that quotation marks while querying.

Comment: Can you show your schema (Sample with "double quotes")? Just curious why do you use "double quotes" in column name, seems a bad choice

Comment: CREATE TABLE feeds (
    uuid uuid,
    variant text,
    "entries" text,
    last_modification timestamp,
    links text,
    template uuid,
    title text,
    uihash text,
    url text,
    version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid, variant)
)

Comment: Again why do you want to use special characters in column names?

Comment: double quotes is used to enclose column with uppercase to maintain uppercase characters

Comment: entires is a reserved keyword, so there is no other way to use it than using double quotation marks